# Does the Doppler effect change frequency?

Tags: frequency, doppler-effect

Would a high-pitched unhearable frequency be heard whilst the doppler effect is in play?

For example, when a car uses its horn whilst travelling by, the pitch shifts as it passes - which is the Doppler effect. What would happen if someone were to play a frequency so high that humans couldn't hear it and went past a bystander? Would the bystander be able to hear the frequency as the pitch shifts? or would it not affect it?

Just a random shower thought that was playing on my mind...

Answer (score 0):

> What would happen if someone were to play a frequency so high that humans couldn't hear it and went past a bystander?

As the car approaches the bystander, they would still not hear the horn, because its frequency would be increased even further by the doppler effect.

As the car moves away from the bystander, they might hear it, if the original frequency of the horn is not too high above the maximum audible frequency ($f_{max}$), and the car is moving fast enough that the doppler effect reduces it below $f_{max}$.